# Using Numpy where to place conditions on Pandas DataFrame while taking Cumulative Sum

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am trying to place a condition on one of the columns in Pandas Dataframe and based on that condition I want to take cumulative sum of another column in the Dataframe. To be more clear here is the example: Suppose my DataFrame `df` as:

```
+-----------+--------------+-----+-------------+
|   Date    | daily_return | dir | size_return |
+-----------+--------------+-----+-------------+
| 2/25/2015 |    -0.000681 |  -1 |   -0.000681 |
| 2/26/2015 |      -0.0015 |  -1 |    -0.00218 |
| 2/27/2015 |    -0.003022 |  -1 |   -0.005203 |
| 3/2/2015  |     0.005776 |   1 |    0.005776 |
| 3/3/2015  |    -0.003772 |  -1 |   -0.003772 |
| 3/4/2015  |     -0.00436 |  -1 |    -0.00755 |
+-----------+--------------+-----+-------------+
```

I've placed a condition on the column `dir` as long as the value in `dir` is equal to `dir.shift(1)` I want to take cumulative sum of column `daily_return` until `dir` is not equal `dir.shift(1)` and when they are not equal I want `daily_return` equal to `size_return`.
The code that I used to generate the above table is as follows:

```
df['size_return'] = np.where(df.dir == df.dir.shift(1), 
                             df.daily_return.cumsum(axis=0), df.daily_return)
```

**The problem with the above table is that I can't figure out why in the last two rows if I sum using above line of code `daily_return` the result is `-0.00755`, I should be getting `-0.00813` (`-0.003772 + -0.00436`).**

There must be an error in my logic written in above code, I can't figure out my mistake?

Second, I do not want value in every row of `size_return` only last row of filtered data frame based on the condition. To be more clear this is how the final table should be looking:

```
+-----------+--------------+-----+-------------+
|   Date    | daily_return | dir | size_return |
+-----------+--------------+-----+-------------+
| 2/25/2015 |    -0.000681 |  -1 |             |
| 2/26/2015 |      -0.0015 |  -1 |             |
| 2/27/2015 |    -0.003022 |  -1 |   -0.005203 |
| 3/2/2015  |     0.005776 |   1 |    0.005776 |
| 3/3/2015  |    -0.003772 |  -1 |             |
| 3/4/2015  |     -0.00436 |  -1 |   -0.008132 |
+-----------+--------------+-----+-------------+
```

Comment: The `cumsum` argument is evaluated (in full) before being passed to the `where`.  Remember this is python, not some custom language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with `groupby` and `cumsum`

```
df.groupby((df.dir==df.dir.shift()).eq(0).cumsum()).daily_return.cumsum()
0   -0.000681
1   -0.002181
2   -0.005203
3    0.005776
4   -0.003772
5   -0.008132
Name: daily_return, dtype: float64
```

If only keep the last one ,using `duplicated`

```
s=(df.dir==df.dir.shift()).eq(0).cumsum()
df['New']=df.groupby(s).daily_return.cumsum().mask(s.duplicated(keep='last'),'')
df
        Date  daily_return  dir  size_return       New
0  2/25/2015     -0.000681   -1    -0.000681          
1  2/26/2015     -0.001500   -1    -0.002180          
2  2/27/2015     -0.003022   -1    -0.005203 -0.005203
3   3/2/2015      0.005776    1     0.005776  0.005776
4   3/3/2015     -0.003772   -1    -0.003772          
5   3/4/2015     -0.004360   -1    -0.007550 -0.008132
```